# Connection to socket.IO namespace not being detected

Tags: node.js, socket.io

In my `routes.js` file I have a route to `/test` as follows:

```
    app.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/test.html');
    var nsp = io.of('/test');
    console.log(nsp);
    nsp.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('connection made');
        socket.on('new_task', function(msg){
            nsp.emit('new_task', msg);
        });
    });
});
```

In `test.html` I have attempted a connection to the `/test` namespace

```
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io('/test');

    $('.exp_addtask').click(function(){
        socket.emit('new_task', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
    });
    socket.on('new_task', function(msg){
        $('#messages').append('<div class="task-item"><div class="toggle"></div><p>' + msg + '</p></div>');
    });
</script>
```

There are no errors on runtime and I see all details of the `nsp` connection when I access `http://localhost/test`, but what I can't see is that a connection has been made when the page is accessed. Can't see any of the sockets triggering either as they would in the global namespace.

**EDIT**: At the end of `index.js` here is how I bring in routes and start the server:

```
 require('./routes')(app);

 http.listen(80, function(){ 
   console.log('listening on *:80'); 
 });
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: which of your log messages are printed to the console on the server side?

Comment: only `console.log(nsp);` when I access /test

Comment: Check out the example at http://socket.io/docs/ again, they put the assignment of the "connection" event handler to the socket outside of the http request handler.

Comment: Yeah it would all work if I put the connection in `index.js` but how would I be able to access different namespaces within different routes?

Comment: Anyways, I think they belong outside of the http request handler. I think assigning the 'connection' handler on every request is not the intended use.

Comment: What happens if you put everything except the sendFile function outside of the handler?

Comment: Got it working now (see answer), thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working, don't need to put anything in the routes section (didn't work either if I put it outside the `/test` route handler)

This successfully works now when I access `/test`:

```
var test = io.of('/test');
test.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('connection to test');
});
```